# Subprocess in Flask app when booted on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I have a flask app, run.py, that uses subprocess to execute a shell file, hello.sh.  The hello.sh file activates a virtual env and starts a security camera program on a raspberry pi.

**run.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def camera_toggle():
    subprocess.Popen('/home/pi/hello.sh')
    return "Hello, world."
```

**hello.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python 
/home/pi/security/pi_surveillance_testing2.py --output 
home/pi/security/output/ --conf /home/pi/security/conf.json
```

**The problem:**
when running run.py from the terminal, everything works as expected. But I've added run.py to the rc.local file so it starts at boot, which does not work.  I have to kill the flask app and restart it from the terminal to get it to work.

Any ideas?  Is this a file permission issue or a stdout/GUI issue?  I've tried variations of subprocess.Popen, subprocess.call, and with different stdout options.  I've also tried shell=True but nothing seems to work.

Comment: 1) Did you make `/home/pi/hello.sh` executable? 2) Always use full paths to executable and to bash: `subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash /home/pi/hello.sh')`. The same for `/etc/rc.local` 3) For debug try to use `subprocess.check_output()` and return str formatted output by flask route function.

Comment: Ok, it works now but the sub process kills after a few seconds and then the text is returned to the URL.

Comment: `sub process kills` it's expected. you need to create daemon if you want it to be running after starting from your code. In case of daemon - you will be able to handle it using your init process (systemd, upstart, ..etc)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into daemon. But it's still confusing why the subprocess in run.py kills when it starts from boot but runs fine when run.py is started from terminal.

Comment: @MartinNoah did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ahmed.B No I am afraid not.  It has been many years and I have since moved on from that.